# Passing USB smart card works with rdesktop but not freerdp

Tags: rdp, remmina, pcscd

rdesktop works great to login to my Windows 7 Enterprise system and passes the ActivKey USB Smart card with no problems. Once the session is started, I can login to VPN and authenticate to websites on the remote system perfectly. Unfortunately I can only get 16 color depth with rdesktop and would like to leverage higher color depths since I use this remote system all day long.

Remmina client and freerdp from the command line both work well at the higher color depth but Reminna doesn't have an option passing the smart card and freerdp doesn't work when I pass it with rdpdr "scard" option.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or is there another tool that might work better?

This works:

```
$ rdesktop -z -a 24 -T myserver -d DOMAIN -u username -x l -P -f -r sound:remote -r scard:"ActivIdentity Activkey_Sim 00 00" xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This connects okay but doesn't pass the smart card:

```
$ $ xfreerdp -d DOMAIN -u username -f --plugin rdpdr --data scard:"ActivIdentity Activkey_Sim 00 00" -- x.x.x.x
loading plugin rdpdr
connected to x.x.x.x:3389
Password: 
freerdp_load_library_symbol: failed to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/freerdp/scard.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/freerdp/scard.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
freerdp_load_plugin: failed to load scard/DeviceServiceEntry
```

I am using:

```
Ubuntu 13.04
remmina 1.0.0-4ubuntu2
freerdp-x11 1.0.1-2ubuntu1
rdesktop 1.7.1-1ubuntu4
pcsc-tools 1.4.21-1
coolkey 1.1.0-12
libccid 1.4.9-1
pcscd 1.8.6-3ubuntu1b1
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Henry

Comment: Final working command for fullscreen, 32bpp, smooth fonts, remote sound, local caching :  $ rdesktop -z -x 0x80 -P -f -a 32 -K -T Notebook -d DOMAIN -u username -r clipboard:PRIMARYCLIPBOARD -r sound:remote -r scard:"ActivIdentity Activkey_Sim 00 00" x.x.x.x

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue. https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/792

I guess smart card is not included with default ubuntu RDP package. When I compiled from source using

```
cmake -DWITH_PCSC=ON -DWITH_SSE2=ON .
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 32bpp with Windows 7 using rdesktop, also make sure that client settings of RDP-Tcp allows the color depth.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks. I thought 24bpp was max. 24bpp is only supported on XP. As you say, 32bpp works well and is the default for Win 7.